# Error while setting up a golden gate replication process, for JSON document convert to rdbms table

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to convert and replicate json document stored in oracle table (source) as clob value to target database (oracle) as rdbms table using oracle goldengate :

```
GGSCI (ggsrv2.localdomain) 39> view params RJSON3

Replicat rjson3
DiscardFile ./dirrpt/rjson3.dsc, Purge
USERID ogg, PASSWORD oracle
Map HR.JSON_TEST_SOURCE, Target HRTRG.JSON_TEST_TARGET,
SQLEXEC (id lookup, QUERY 'SELECT json_value(jsondoc, '$.IDNumber') AS J_ID, json_value(jsondoc, '$.Description') AS J_DESCRIPTION, json_value(jsondoc, '$.DecimalNumber') AS J_DECIMAL FROM
HRTRG.JSON_TEST_SOURCE
WHERE ID = :V_ID ',
PARAMS (V_ID = ID)),
J_ID = @GETVAL(lookup.J_ID)),
J_DESCRIPTION = @GETVAL(lookup.J_DESCRIPTION)),
J_DECIMAL = @GETVAL(lookup.J_DECIMAL))
);
```

## Error message:

```
2019-01-06 07:56:54  WARNING OGG-10173  (rjson3.prm) line 4 column 317: Parsing error, value "'@'" syntax error.
2019-01-06 07:56:54  WARNING OGG-10173  (rjson3.prm) line 4: Parsing error, option [sqlexec] for parameter [map] has unrecognized value "=".
2019-01-06 07:56:54  WARNING OGG-10173  (rjson3.prm) line 4: Parsing error, option [sqlexec] for parameter [map] has unrecognized value "J_ID"."
Database version 12cR2,GoldenGate version 12.3
```

## Source Table:

```
SQL> desc HR.JSON_TEST_SOURCE;
 Name     Null?    Type
 -------  -------- ------------
 ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 JSONDOC           CLOB
```

## Sample data on Source table:

```
SQL> col JSONDOC for a55
SQL> select * from HR.JSON_TEST_SOURCE;

        ID JSONDOC
---------- -------------------------------------------------------
      1600 { "IDNumber"      : 01,
              "Description"   : "I am Shanoj",
              "DecimalNumber" :

      1601 { "IDNumber"      : 02,
              "Description"   : "I am Joby",
              "DecimalNumber" : 1

      1602 { "IDNumber"      : 03,
              "Description"   : "I am Siriram",
              "DecimalNumber"

      1603 { "IDNumber"      : 04,
              "Description"   : "No idea who I am",
              "DecimalNumb
```

## Target Table:

```
SQL> desc HRTRG.JSON_TEST_TARGET
 Name           Null?    Type
 -------------- -------- --------------
 J_ID           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4000)
 J_DESCRIPTION           VARCHAR2(4000)
 J_DECIMAL               VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may to use some adapters. Another option is to use a materialized view from target to get the JSon values as records using json_values().